# Using OnTouchListener to play audio until release

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, motionevent

I'm trying to come up with a way to play an audio clip, and have it loop, until the button associated with that audio clip is released, much like a sample pad. How would one do this?

Comment: I have edited your question because you are asking about *android development*, not the IDE.

Comment: Whoops, didn't even realize that.

Comment: No worries. Have you tried to implement anything related to your problem? If so, please [edit].

Comment: I'm getting very close. I just need to find a way to ignore a MotionEvent.MOVE. I just want to be able to hold the press down, but when that happens, the move event happens very easily and resets the audio.